# Looking for a ghost story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

It was probably in a children's anthology, and I've already searched through the "Scary Stories to tell in the Dark" books.

I know it took place at a haunted/cursed lake/bay/island, I think Indian burial grounds were involved. At some point a cop drowned while trying to rescue someone who was drowning. At the end of the story the protagonist has escaped from the water and is put in a police car only to realize the drivers clothes are soaking wet and her name is the same as the one who had previously drowned as she drives into the lake.